# Subdifferential questions in Evans' book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $K \subset R^n$ be a closed, convex, nonempty set. Define
$$
I[x] := \begin{cases}0&\mbox{If }x\in K\\
\infty&\mbox{If }x\notin K\end{cases}
$$
Explicitly determine $A=\partial I$,$J_{\lambda}=(I+{\lambda}A)^{-1}$,$A_{\lambda}=\frac{I-J_{\lambda}}{\lambda}({\lambda >0})$ in terms of the geometry of $K$.

Comment: I have no idear on the queation! Wish someone help me solve this question,thanks a lot

Comment: The most important thing is determining $A=\partial I$. Once you have done this the rest is easier. Try to work out the case in which $K$ is the unit circle in the plane. Clearly, if $x$ is interior to the circle, then $A[x]=\{0\}$, and if $x$ is outside the circle then $A[x]=\varnothing$. What happens when $x$ is on the boundary? Once you understand this, redo the reasoning with a square instead of the circle.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, do you know what is the meaning of the notation $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$?

Comment: Is $I$ in $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$ the indicator function of $K$, or is it $Iu=u$?

Comment: @Tomás: $I$ is the identity. Indeed $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$ is called *nonlinear resolvent*, if I recall correctly. (I'm taking my copy of Evans's book to check.)

Comment: Yes it is the identity. The point is that, even if $A=\partial I$ (there is a notational conflict here, this $I$ is the indicator function) is a multi-valued function, it happens that the equation (with $\lambda >0$ a fixed parameter)
$$u+\lambda A[u]\ni w $$
has a unique solution $u$ for each $w$, and so the operator $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$ is well-defined and single-valued. Of course here $I$ is the identity.